# Ошибка в коде построения спиральной матрицы

Tags: python

Задание на Python:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задание я попытался решить вот что получилось:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

def fill_spiral_matrix(n):
result = [[]]

dx, dy = 1, 0
x, y = 0, 0
arr = [[None] * n for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(1, n ** 2 + 1):
    arr[x][y] = i
    nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy
    if 0 <= nx < n and 0 <= ny < n and not arr[nx][ny]:
        x, y = nx, ny
    else:
        dx, dy = -dy, dx
        x, y = x + dx, y + dy
    result = list(zip(*arr))
#for x in list(zip(*arr)):
#print(*x)
return result


#fill_spiral_matrix(int(input()))
```

Закоментированые строки я использовал для того чтоб посмотреть как работает функция в консоле. Функция почему-то не справляется когда ей передают числа 1, 10 и 1000. Помогите найти ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Тестом не пользовался, но в терминале отрабатывает с любыми числами

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
def fill_spiral_matrix(n):
    result = []
    x, y, dx, dy = 0, 0, 1, 0
    arr = [[0] * n for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(1, n**2+1):
        arr[x][y] = i
        nx, ny = x+dx, y+dy
        if 0 <= nx < n and 0 <= ny < n and not arr[nx][ny]:
            x, y = nx, ny
        else:
            dx, dy = -dy, dx
            x, y = x+dx, y+dy
    for x in list(zip(*arr)):
        result.append(list(x))
    return result


print(fill_spiral_matrix(int(input(' Одна строка '))))

for row in fill_spiral_matrix(int(input(' Построчно '))):
    print(row)
```

Comment: Оно работает! Unite тест твоя функция прошла! Огромное спасибо!